# v$ tables not recognized in a sql statement of a shell script

Tags: oracle, scripting

I have .sh script with this block:

```
sqlplus -S / as sysdba <<EOFILE

set feedback off
set lines 2000
set pages 20000
col db_size for a15
alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';

select * from ( select "START_TIME", "END_TIME", INPUT_BYTES_DISPLAY db_size from v$RMAN_BACKUP_JOB_DETAILS order by "END_TIME" DESC) where ROWNUM <= 5;

EOFILE

EOF
```

But output is this error:

> select * from ( select "START_TIME", "END_TIME", INPUT_BYTES_DISPLAY
>   db_size from v order by "END_TIME" DESC) where ROWNUM <= 5
>                                                                                     * ERROR at line 1: ORA-04044: procedure, function, package, or type is not allowed here

I know there is problem with accessing to v$RMAN_BACKUP_JOB_DETAILS but how should i solve this?

I tried:

```
v\$RMAN_BACKUP_JOB_DETAILS
'v$RMAN_BACKUP_JOB_DETAILS'
"v$RMAN_BACKUP_JOB_DETAILS"
```

Can someone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: `sqlplus -S / as sysdba <<'EOFILE' ...`

Putting quotes tells the shell to not interpret the contents of the here document: it does not try to interpret $XXX in the here document as a shell variable.

Comment: Man, it worked!! Thanks a lot. Can you easily explain me difference between EOFILE a 'EOFILE'.